# Register bean with Grails for MeterRegistryCustomizer

Tags: spring-boot, grails, grails-3.3, micrometer

Having followed [Spring Boot Metrics documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html), I was able to set metrics logging for datadog easily. The only remaining stuff is to set custom tags for my instances. With Spring Boot, you can do it by registering a new bean:

```
@Bean
MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> metricsCommonTags() {
    return registry -> registry.config().commonTags("region", "us-east-1");
}
```

However, I'm not able to register it in Grails 3. Not in `resource.groovy` nor in application main class `Application.groovy`. Is there any way how to set this in Grails 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Grails 3, You should put the below code to `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy`:

```
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry
import io.micrometer.spring.autoconfigure.MeterRegistryCustomizer

class CommonTagCustomizer implements MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> {

    void customize(MeterRegistry registry) {
        registry.config().commonTags("host", "myapp-dev")
    }
}

beans = {
    commonTags(CommonTagCustomizer) {}
}
```

Comment: This is exactly it! Thanks. I was having troubles with closure being declared without curly brackets which is not possible in Groovy lang.